# Akka.net testing actor using Context.DI()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, akka.net

I think this should be an "easy" one. I'm trying to test the behavior of an actor that performs a child actor creation when receiving a message. I'm using `Context.DI().Props<ChildActor>()` to create it and that's fine however there is an exception being thrown when I try to run the tests:

```
Cause: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Akka.DI.Core.DIActorContextAdapter.Props[TActor]()
```

And I have installed the Akka.TestKit, the Akka.DI.TestKit, etc. Is there anything I need to configure/set in my test to "mock" the Context.DI()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Akka.DI.TestKit is used to test custom IoC container plugins (like Autofac, NInject etc.) for compatibility with Akka. They are not used for testing custom code.

If you want to mock `Context.DI()` you probably need to supply container and register your mocks in it.